# How to center the wrapped cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, wrap

It might have been asked in certain questions, but none of them worked for me as I would like to center the wrapped columns in latex table and couldn't come with a clean and easy solution. 
I.e. here I am interested in centering the text of c3 and c4. I would like to avoid macros, newcommands and magical addons. Does latex provide such trivial need?

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\small
\caption{Caption}
\label{table:kaiserTest}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | l | m{3cm} | m{2cm} | m{1.9cm} | }
\hline
    \textbf{C1} & c2 & c3 which has a long title & c4 which also has a long tile\\ \hline
    text & text  & 99 & [7-11] \\ \hline
    text & text & 53  & [4-6] \\ \hline     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the usual commands such as `\centering` or `begin{center}` work in that context.  or use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}` to avoid specifying `\centering` in each cell. The `>` syntax assumes `array` package but you are already using that (as that defines `m`)

Answer (score 4):

The `array` package provides such functionality: just add `>{\centering\arraybackslash}`before the specifiers of the last two columns:

[image]

For column heads, you also may use the `\thead` command , from `makecell`, if you break lines on your own. This command also allows for a common formatting (e.g.boldface).